# Fourth order tensor evaluation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I try to evaluate the following equation:

```
FGammaijkl(i,j,k,l)=xi(i)*(xi*Cijkl(:,j,k,:)*xi)^(-1)*xi(l);
```

Where `FGammaijkl` is and integral operator and `Cijkl(:,j,k,:)` is the stiffness tensor. They are both 3-dimensional fourth order tensors, e.g. `size=(3,3,3,3)` and `xi` is a 3-dimensional vector. When I evaluate the above, I get the following warning:

> Inputs must be 2-D, or at least one input must be scalar.
>   To compute elementwise TIMES, use TIMES (.*) instead.

How can I evaluate these specific rows of the  fourth order tensor?

Comment: Did you try `.*` instead of `*` like the error suggested?

Comment: I did, that only works in 2D as well. However, .* is element wise multiplication, while I need to contract the  fourth order tensor with a dot product with the surrounding vectors xi  to a scalar.